# OS X Server App ail not accept login credentials

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion

I cannot login to the server app and i know for sure all the login info is right. every time i enter my password the name window shakes to tell me it's invalid. I never post unless I'm out of ideas and I need it to be up so I can host my splash page tonight. i've spoken with "certified apple" specialists at some local mac stores and they are stumped too. Something is going on with the apache server, that's all i know for sure. I'll be monitoring this closely so any requests for info, etc. can be filled instantly. Thanks in advance.

here's a few things i've noticed:

I can ssh successfully into the server address as both root and admin.
I've been fussing with the workgroup manager and could use guidance if that's where the problem lies.
console shows this message repeatedly (org.apache.httpd[1890]) Exited with code: 1).

Much appreciated,

harry